# Как получить название исключения в питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, try

Есть некий код с обработчиком ошибок:

```
def return_exception():
    try:
        x = 1 / 0
        # Здесь происходит некая ошибка
    except:
        exception_name = # ???
        return exception_name
```

Как получить название исключения, произошедшего в блоке `except`? В приведенном примере должно вернуть `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: Ну для начала захватить его в переменную `except Exception as exc:` а потом в этой переменной посмотреть что надо

Comment: @andreymal, не знал, что так можно было... ни в каких справочниках такого не видел(

Comment: Какие-то странные у вас спровочники, обычно во всех это написано, и там же написано, что пустой `except:` без ничего это плохо

Comment: @andreymal, почему плохо? Всю жизнь так делал, ничего не происходило

Comment: Потому что пустой except также перехватит исключения KeyboardInterrupt и SystemExit, которые занимаются завершением работы программы, и это создаёт риск, что вы не сможете завершить программу

Comment: @andreymal, надо же, не знал. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Можно выполнить код без try..except и посмотреть с каким исключением он завершается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так:

```py
try:
    x = 1 / 0
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc.__class__.__name__)
```

Вывод:

```
ZeroDivisionError
```

Comment: Интересный метод.

Comment: Еще кстати нагуглил, есть sys.exc_info(), там даже трейсбек получить можно!

Comment: @Глеб а для получения трейсбека есть модуль с названием traceback )

Answer (score -1):

```
def return_exception:
    try:
        x = 1 / 0
        # Здесь происходит некая ошибка
    except Exception as error:
        exception_name = str(error)
        return exception_name
```

Вместо error можно использовать любое другое название

Comment: А куда делись скобки после имени функции?

Comment: В данном случае (с `ZeroDivisionError`) код возвращает `"division by zero"` - по-моему автору вопроса нужно не это.

Comment: @wchistow а скобок и в тексте вопроса тоже нет

Comment: @andreymal, теперь есть